# .Net MVC4 Culture set correct, but validation still English

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a very basic .MVC site, that uses Danish language.

I could set the Culture in the beginning of the page:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
    Culture = "da-DK";
}
```

But it is already correct, so I doubt it matters.

Then I have my input field:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Price)
```

It is a decimal in the model.

And then I have the submit button

```
<input type="submit" value="Opret" />
```

I don't know if it matters, but I use the same partial view for edit and create, but culture is also correct in the inner view.

When I insert 5,60 in the Price field then it complains and says that it should be a number.

What am I missing?

(I apologize if this has been asked before, I really couldn't find it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have mentioned in your question falls into the globalization that is not completely supported by ASP.NET MVC. So you need some changes that is described in the following post.

[ASP.NET MVC 4 jQuery Validation Globalization](http://blog.instance-factory.com/?p=268)

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I tried to get it from nuget, but that crashed my studio, so I just got it from https://github.com/jquery/globalize